# Resizable panel that resizes horizontally

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to make a resizable panel that is is 100% the height of the application, and resizes horizontally when the user clicks and drags on the edge of the div.

Is this built into electron, or do I need to use some sort of library to do this?

### Edit

CSS:

```
.connections{
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #252526;
    color: #cccccc;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');

$(function () {
    $('.connections').resizable();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="connections col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
        <table class="results table table-striped table-bordered">
            <!-- Table Contents Here -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQueryUI resizeable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)